# Why does square integrable function have a value of zero at infinity?

Tags: integration, functions

My textbook claims that square integrable function decay to 0 at infinity, but is it not true that a square integrable function can have a non zero value at infinity but decay to 0 at negative infinity?

That is imagine we define a range of [0,1], and at $x=1$ we have a delta, therefore if we integrate 0 to 1, we would get 1, now if we extend the delta to a position of infinity we would still get a area of 1 if we integrate from $-\infty $ to $\infty$. What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Doesn't the delta function you mention decay to $0$ at infinity? It looks like it does. 
Try proving it by contradiction.

Comment: sorry if its trivial, but i move the delta to infinity $\delta(x-\infty)$, therefore $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$

Answer (score 3):

Either the textbook makes a wrong claim, or you interpreted it incorrectly. The function
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max(0, 1-2^n|x-n|)
$$
is square integrable on $\mathbb R$ but $\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

What  is true is that for any square integrable function on $\mathbb R$ we have $\liminf_{x\to\infty} |f(x)|=0$.

Comment: it may be worth noting this function is a set of triangles centered at the integers with height 1 and width $2^{-n}$.