# Prove that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max(0, 1-2^n|x-n|)$ is square integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577894/why-does-square-integrable-function-have-a-value-of-zero-at-infinity), @Post No Bulls claims that 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max(0, 1-2^n|x-n|)
$$
is square integrable on $\mathbb R$ but $\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

How to prove that $f$ is square integrable on $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: By first drawing a picture and then doing a geometric series.

Comment: Those are just triangles with base length $2^{-n}$ and the middle of the base is at $x=2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The intervals $(n-\frac 1 {2^{n}},n+\frac 1 {2^{n}})$ are disjoint.  A particular point $x$ can belong at most one of these. When $x$ is in $(n-\frac 1 {2^{n}},n+\frac 1 {2^{n}})$ the value of $f(x)$ lies between $0$ and $1$. Hence $\int f(x)^{2} dx \leq \sum \frac 2  {2^{n}} <\infty$.

$0 \leq f \leq 1$, $f(n)=1$ and $f(n+\frac  1 {2^{n}})=0$ for all $n$. Hence $\lim\sup_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist.