# When do quadratically integrable functions vanish at infinity?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions, quantum-mechanics

In quantum mechanics we use **quadratically integrable functions** ($\psi \in L^2$).
This means
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\psi(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x < \infty. $$

I'm interested in the question when those function vanish at infinity, i.e.
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} \psi(x) = 0. $$

I know that this is not the case for every function in $L^2$, see for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384992/square-integrable-function-that-doesnt-go-to-zero) or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577894/why-does-square-integrable-function-have-a-value-of-zero-at-infinity).

I found in a similar question [something interesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384992/square-integrable-function-that-doesnt-go-to-zero/385051#385051):

> Suppose $f : \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ is uniformly continuous, and $f\in L^p$ for some $p\geq 1$. Then $|f(x)|\to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Another interesting answer is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377036/a-question-on-use-of-square-integrable-functions/1377063#1377063).

*My questions are:*

1. How can one prove the given statement?
2. What are other cases where quadratically integrable functions vanish at infinity?
3. Which cases are relevant in physics (for quantum mechanics)?

---

**Edit:**

My first question was answered in the comments by @reuns.

**My remaining question is:**

What criteria (beside uniform continuity) do exist, so that quadratically integrable functions vanish (or not) at infinity?

Comment: The uniform continuity implies that if $|f(a)| > c$ then $|f| > c/2$ on $[a-b,a+b]$. If $|f(a_n)|> c$ for some sequence $a_n\to \infty$ then $\|f\|_{L^p}=\infty$

Comment: Just a remark: I think if $\psi$ is differentiable it must tend to $0$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: @K.defaoite: No, this is not even true if $\psi$ is infinitely differentiable. It is true, however, if the derivative is bounded, since then $\psi$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial sufficient condition is that $f$ is absolutely continuous with $f'\in L_1(\mathbb R)$. Indeed, the absolute continuity means that
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt\text,$$
and $f'\in L_1(\mathbb R)$ implies that $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\,\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt$$
exist which can be seen from a Cauchy-like criterion, observing that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\,\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-N,N]}\lvert f'(t)\rvert\,dt=0.$$
(The latter follows for instance from Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.)

Note that $f'\in L_1(\mathbb R)$ does even for continuous $f'$ not imply the boundedness of $f'$ and thus also does not imply that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

On the other hand, the assumption $f\in L_p(\mathbb R)$ would be used here only to verify that the limits are not different from zero...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Every absolutely continuous function is also uniformly continuous and this case is already answered for me. I‘m especially searching for other cases. I would be very happy if those cases include many "physical meaningful functions", for example differentiable functions etc.

Comment: (Local) absolute continuity and uniform continuity on a non-compact interval are independent properties: Neither implies the other. At the end of my posting it is indicated how to find an example which is not uniformly continuous. In case this example is not clear: Choose a continuously differentiable integrable (on $\mathbb R$) function with unbounded (on $\mathbb R$) derivative. Due to the unbounded continuous derivative the function cannot be uniformly continuous.